# How do I check if an array has an object with a certain property and then find that property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I have an array which looks something like:

```
var arr = [
  {name: "Joe", id: "p01"}
];
```

I want to first, check if an input matches anything with the same `name` property. For example, if the user inputs "Steven", I want it to check for any object with the name "Steven".

Secondly, I want to get the `id` of whatever they inputted, if it exists.

Sorry if this is a big ask.

Comment: `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [
  {name: "Joe", id: "p01"}
];

//need to find array item where object.name is Joe - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
const obj = arr.find(item => {
    //item = {name: "Joe", id: "p01"}
    return item.name === 'Joe'
});

//obj = {name: "Joe", id: "p01"}
//check if item exists and return id value;
const id = obj && obj.id;

//to filter array and get only items where name is Joe - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
const items = arr.filter(item => item.name === 'Joe');
//items = [{name: "Joe", id: "p01"}]

//to get the list of ids with condition
const ids = arr.reduce((results, obj) => {
 if (obj.name === "Joe") results.push(obj.id);
}, [])
//ids = ["p01"]

//one line solution
const { id } = arr.find(item => item.name === 'Joe') || {};
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26234094)

Answer (score 0):

```
const foundItem = arr.find(item => item.name === searchQuery) // searchQuery = Steven

if (foundItem === -1) {
  console.log("Item not found")
} else {
  console.log("Item found", foundItem)
  console.log("Item id: ", fountItem.id)
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26234093)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, Hope this will help you

```js
let arr = [
  {name: "Joe", id: "p01"}
];

let searchQuery = 'Joe'
let finalResult = arr.find(({name}) => name.includes(searchQuery));
finalResult = (finalResult && finalResult.id) ? finalResult.id :"No Match Found"
console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done though `filter` as well.

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "Joe", id: "p01"},
  {name: "Steve", id: "p02"},
  {name: "Smith", id: "p01"},
];



console.log(arr.filter(i=>i.name.includes('Ste')))
   var ids = arr.filter(i=>i.name.includes('Ste')).map(k=>k.id);
console.log(ids);
```